# How to apply FileField Button click in FF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I have this html code :

```
    <form name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" action="">

    <div dir="rtl" style="position:absolute; left: 2px; top: 0px;">
       <input name="fileField2" type="file" class="accountItemFilefield" id="fileField2" />
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute; z-index:2;">
         <img onclick="$('#fileField2').trigger('click'); " style="cursor:pointer" src="images/browse.png" width="83" height="29" alt="" />
   </div>

    </form>
```

This code is not working in FF and it's working successfully in IE and I don't know what is the problem.

I also tried this code :

```
$('#fileField2').click();
```

and this one :

```
document.getElementById('fileField2').click();
```

all of them are working in IE bur not in FF.

How I can solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tag should be javascript, not java

Comment: @Geoffrey De Smet: Sorry, type mistake, fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security restriction to prevent malicious sites from unexpectedly showing the file upload dialog.

I don't think there is a way around this. In fact, I'm surprised that IE still allows it.

Comment: Actually google chrome allows it as well, i think firefox is the only that doesn't

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById('fileField2').click();` worked when I tried it. (I didn't try the other versions.)

The only security restriction applies if you try to launch the filepicker at a time when a popup would be blocked, in which case you get the regular blocked popup notification.